# Stop rendering UseEffect of Click of a specific function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my Application when ever i change the number i want run the UseEffect Hook and re-render the updated values in the array which is working, but one condition i don't want to run the use UseEffect Hook is when i click addRow function i want bank field should be added in the rows except the number

**JsCode**

```
     const [number, setNumber] = useState(3);
     const [data, setData] = useState([]);
     const [insValue,setInstValue]=useState(90); 


useEffect(() => {
    const list = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
      let ins = instValue/number;
      list.push({
        insNo: i,
        installmentAmount: ins,
        chequeNumber: '',
      });
    }
 
    setData(list);
    
  }, [number]);

  const addRow = () => {
    setNumber((number) => number + 1);
    console.log('Add item clicked');
    data.push({
      insNo: number + 1,
      installmentAmount: '',
      chequeNumber: ''
    });
    const list = [...data];
    setData(list);
  };
```

**Html**

```
<div onClick={addRow}>
        ADD ROW
</div>
```

currently what it is happening is when i click on add row number get changed and useffect Runs and data get updated i need is blank field in the row on the last object of an array

**Output Getting**

```
[{"insNo":1,"installmentAmount":22.5,"chequeNumber":""},
{"insNo":2,"installmentAmount":22.5,"chequeNumber":""}
{"insNo":3,"installmentAmount":22.5,"chequeNumber":""}
{"insNo":4,"installmentAmount":22.5,"chequeNumber":""}]
```

**Output i need on click of addRow**

```
 [{"insNo":1,"installmentAmount":30,"chequeNumber":""},
    {"insNo":2,"installmentAmount":30,"chequeNumber":""}
    {"insNo":3,"installmentAmount":30,"chequeNumber":""}
    {"insNo":4,"installmentAmount":"","chequeNumber":""}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you exactly want.

But according to your code, you can't get the desired result.
Because you increase `number` and add a new row with empty values. And `useEffect` updates your array `data` again. So the `installmentAmount` in the last row will be filled.

To avoid it, you can change the code block like the following:

```
  const initialNumber = 3;  // Define initial value to check if data array is in the initial step.
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(initialNumber);
  
  // ... ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const list = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
      list.push({
        insNo: i,
        installmentAmount: i > initialNumber && i == number? '' : instValue/number,
        chequeNumber: '',
      });
    }
 
    setData(list);    
  }, [number]);

  const addRow = () => {
    setNumber((number) => number + 1);
    console.log('Add item clicked');
    
    const list = [...data];
    list.push({
      insNo: number + 1,
      installmentAmount: '',
      chequeNumber: ''
    });
    
    setData(list);
  };
```

Comment: you got my question right but one issue is there on this approach is on initial load the last row data is empty i don't want that i want last row data to be empty on click of addRow function except the index no

Comment: @SamMukherjee, `number` state should start from 3 or dynamic value?

Comment: @SamMukherjee, please check the updated code on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data is refreshed again into the useEffect when you change number, losing all data.

You can avoid change number state at click, since the new data is already being saved manually.

<s>setNumber((number) => number + 1);</s>